# Add new table column that's left aligned in table

Tags: vaadin, tablecolumn

We're developing a web application using the Vaadin framework.

In this app I have an existing table with a range a columns. On a user action I want to remove some of the existing columns and add some other additional columns.

This proved quite easy, however, I want the added column to be placed as the first column in the table, on the out most left edge of the table, and I can't seem to find any support for this action. Every column that's added is by default placed as the last column, in the out most right of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is to set your

```
table.setVisibleColumns(your sorted order of columns)
```

and also

```
table.setColumnReorderingAllowed(false)
```

it might be good to throw in a force of relaoding the datasource so

```
table.setContainerDataSource(table.getContainerDataSource());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Marthin! Setting up new arrays for the visible columns sounds like a neat idea, I'll try it out!

Comment: I've tried it out and adding all the columns to the table again in an array with the new column indexed first fixed the problem. Thanks for your help!